# Detect what's going on a window tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, detection

Is it possible to detect the activity on an opened tab from a different website?

For example, a visitor clicked a window tab from my website to example.com, I want to detect when he presses some button inside, how is it possible?

Comment: You can't do that, it's a security risk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible, because as mentioned above it's a huge security risk. Imagine the possibilities this would open up for invasion of privacy.

Disclaimer notwithstanding, the only way to do this would be via a browser extension/add-on or with an application running on the same computer as the browser.